# Migrating SSAS Changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssas

Assume you have 2 SSAS databases, DB1 and DB2, that are identical.

Now they branch off. Changes A and B are made to DB1 and changes C and D are made to DB2.

Is there an easy method to migrate changes A and B from DB1 to DB2 without overwriting changes C and D made in DB2?

I'm using SSAS 2005 - does this functionality improve in 2008? Third-party tools that do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to overwrite changes C and D on db2, you can do a SSAS DB Synchronize.  More information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174928(v=sql.90).aspx

edit: I just reread your question and saw that both db's are running on the same server. I've only ever synchronized db's from two different SSAS servers.  I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to sync on one instance.

Comment: No, I want to keep C and D. Consider db1 the base code and db2 to be a client's version w/ some customization (C and D).